# Logging in separates files in rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I am configuring rsyslog in order it logs in separate files, identified by the port through which the log event arrives.

In order to avoid opening too much ports, I was trying to see if there is any way of making that differed loging but based on the content of the arriving notification.

For example, if I have the following line:

```
Tue Dec 01 2015 00:20:32 [apps_time_logs]: tid(200756305)[response] gtid(200756289): 2015-12-01T00:20:32-03:00  TID: 200756289  Transaccion: response   IP: 127.0.0.1   URI: http://example.org/app.jspx    Response: 200 OK    BL  2492    IL  1   TL  2493
```

I would like to identify that "[apps_time_logs]" tag to send it to the app_time.log file.

Here is my current rsyslog.conf file:

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
#########################################################

$RuleSet dp10514
*.*     /var/log/datapower/dp10514.log

$RuleSet dp10515
*.*     /var/log/datapower/dp10515.log


# and now define listners bound to the relevant ruleset
$InputTCPServerBindRuleset dp10514
$InputTCPServerRun 10514

$InputTCPServerBindRuleset dp10515
$InputTCPServerRun 10515

# start log rotation via outchannel
# outchannel definiation
#$outchannel dp10515,/var/log/datapower/dp10515, 1048576,/root/datapower.sh
#  activate the channel and log everything to it
#*.* :omfile:$dp10515
# end log rotation via outchannel
```

Is there any configuration step that may help me achieve that?

Comment: Lines 3 & 4 of the config file you posted point to helpful resources. I'd recommend that you try those, then re-post with specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your target logfile

```
sudo touch /var/log/app_time.log
```

Confer ownership such that rsyslog has permissions to write to it, on Ubuntu you could use:

```
chown -vR syslog:adm /var/log/app_time.log
```

Make your entry into `rsyslog.conf`

```
# the rsyslog "contains" keyword need to match a string within that rule
:msg, contains, "apps_time_logs" /var/log/app_time.log
```

restart - or ideally use `reload` if possible

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I will be trying that and get back here. Do you know if there's a limitation towards the amount of concurrent log rules?